# How to implement SQL Groupby in RAPIDS

Tags: python, rapids

I'm seeking to translate an SQL query to use RAPIDS.  Consider the simplified query below:

```sql
(SELECT min(a), max(b), c
FROM T
GROUP BY c) AS result
```

I have validated the code below, but is this the optimal solution?  Is sorting on the group key necessary?  Is there a cleaner / more idiomatic way to write it?

```py
from pygdf import DataFrame as gdf

T = gdf(...)
df = gdf({'a':T.a, 'c':T.c}).groupby('c').min().sort_values(by='c')
df['max_b'] = gdf({'b':T.b, 'c':T.c}).groupby('c').max().sort_values(by='c').max_b
result = gdf({'a': df.min_a, 'b': df.max_b, 'c':df.c})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your aggregation using the `.agg` function to make it more straightforward:

```
from pygdf import DataFrame as gdf

T = gdf(...)
df = gdf({'a':T.a, 'b': T.b, 'c':T.c}).groupby('c').agg({'a': 'min', 'b': 'max'})
result = gdf({'a': df.min_a, 'b': df.max_b, 'c':df.c})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BlazingSQL](http://blazingsql.com) which is a SQL engine built on top of RAPIDS. Full disclosure, I work for BlazingSQL.

```
from blazingsql import BlazingContext
bc = BlazingContext()

# Create Table from GDF
bc.create_table('myTableName', gdf)

# Query
result = bc.sql('SELECT min(a), max(b), c FROM main.myTableName GROUP BY c').get()
result_gdf = result.columns

#Print GDF 
print(result_gdf)
```